# Making this quiz time restricted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on an interactive quiz, and I came across one problem. I need to add some sort of time restriction to it (Lets say 5s for testing purposes), so that when the time runs out, no matter at which stage user is, quiz should skip to results part and count all un-answered questions as wrong.

here is my code:

```
jQuery(function(){
    var tourismQuiz = {
        answers: { q1: 'd', q2: 'd', q3: 'a', q4: 'c', q5: 'a', q6: 'd', q7: 'd', q8: 'a', q9: 'c', q10: 'a' },
        questionLenght: 10,
        checkAnswers: function() {
            var arr = this.answers;
            var ans = this.userAnswers;
            var resultArr = []
            for (var p in ans) {
                var x = parseInt(p) + 1;
                var key = 'q' + x;
                var flag = false;
                if (ans[p] == 'q' + x + '-' + arr[key]) {
                    flag = true;
                }
                else {
                    flag = false;
                }
                resultArr.push(flag);
            }
            return resultArr;
        },
        init: function(){
            jQuery('.btnNext').click(function(){
                if (jQuery('input[type=radio]:checked:visible').length == 0) {

                    return false;
                }
                jQuery(this).parents('.questionContainer').fadeOut(500, function(){
                    jQuery(this).next().fadeIn(500);
                });
                var el = jQuery('#progress');
                el.width(el.width() + 60 + 'px');
            });
            jQuery('.btnPrev').click(function(){
                jQuery(this).parents('.questionContainer').fadeOut(500, function(){
                    jQuery(this).prev().fadeIn(500)
                });
                var el = jQuery('#progress');
                el.width(el.width() - 60 + 'px');
            })
            jQuery('.btnShowResult').click(function(){
                var arr = jQuery('input[type=radio]:checked');
                var ans = tourismQuiz.userAnswers = [];
                for (var i = 0, ii = arr.length; i < ii; i++) {
                    ans.push(arr[i].getAttribute('id'))
                }
            })
            jQuery('.btnShowResult').click(function(){
                jQuery('#progress').width(300);
                jQuery('#progressKeeper').hide();
                var results = tourismQuiz.checkAnswers();
                var resultSet = '';
                var trueCount = 0;
                for (var i = 0, ii = results.length; i < ii; i++){
                    if (results[i] == true) {
                        trueCount = trueCount + 2;
                    } else {
                        trueCount = trueCount - 1;
                    }
                    resultSet += '<div> Question ' + (i + 1) + ' is ' + results[i] + '</div>'

                    if (trueCount <= 5) {
                        jQuery("body").css("background-color", "red");
                    } else {
                        jQuery("body").css("background-color", "green");
                    }
                }

                resultSet += '<div class="totalScore">Your total score is ' + trueCount + ' / 20</div>'
                jQuery('#resultKeeper').html(resultSet).show();
            })
        }
    };
    tourismQuiz.init();
})
```

Therefore, instead of waiting for user to press `.btnShowResult` to finish the test, the function that is executed by pressing this button should be executed if time runs out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` as last statement of your `init function` and write the functionality binded with `jQuery('.btnShowResult').` in a separate function add it in `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout("show_result", 20000);
```

Also, use for instance `.clearTimeout(timeoutVariable)` to reset the timeout if the user presses the button within the time limit.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout window.setTimeout, this should get you started: 
Calls a function or executes a code snippet after specified delay.

So you'd want to give the user some time (5000 ms) to answer a question before forwarding them onto the next question, something like:

```
//Psuedocode:

var askNextQuestion, timer ;

askNextQuestion = function(){
 // ... render the question or do whatever
 timer = setTimeout(askNextQuestion, 5000);
 // .. do any clean up and check to see if it's the last question etc.
};

askNextQuestion();
```

I won't try and explain it better than Mozilla!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Save a timestamp for when the question is presented, and then compare that to the timestamp for when the user commits the answer. If the compared time is more than the limit the answer has been commited to late.

Presentation of the countdown could be just graphical, eg. a CSS3 animation of the width of a bar from 100% with to 0%. Exchange 'slow' for your time limit in seconds.

```
$("#bar").animate({ width:'0%' },'slow');
```

Check http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp for tips on setting up the animation!